# none when requesting via SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to retrieve folders and files at the path /test/TechLibrary through the SharePoint API using Python. However, in response to the actions /Folders and /Files, I always receive an empty response 'd': {'results': []}'. However, I can log in with the same user making the request via the UI and see the folders and files that exist there. Why can't I do the same through the API?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHHFm.png)
return 'd': {'results': []}

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently this SharePoint API can only obtain files in the Shared Documents library, so the result you return is empty.

Comment: But why am I able to access the specific file in the folder then? I mean, I can access it using the path https://site.ru/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/test/TechLibrary/982/001.nwc')/$value and download the file. However, I cannot view files or folders.

Comment: This is currently the case. If you want to get all the files in the folder, it is recommended that you use a loop.